# how to add jvm options in quarkusDev

Tags: java, quarkus

I'm using quarkus and pulsar client in java 17.

```
2022-10-06 18:28:05,964 WARN  [org.apa.pul.com.uti.net.DnsResolverUtil] (Quarkus Main Thread) Cannot get DNS TTL settings from sun.net.InetAddressCachePolicy class: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class org.apache.pulsar.common.util.netty.DnsResolverUtil cannot access class sun.net.InetAddressCachePolicy (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export sun.net to unnamed module @6743e411
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.Reflection.newIllegalAccessException(Reflection.java:392)
```

I need add jvm options `--add-opens=java.base/sun.net=ALL-UNNAMED`.

What should I do if I use gradle?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jvm.args property from command line:

```
mvn quarkus:dev -Djvm.args=...
```

Or specify the same in Maven's parameters:

```
<project ...>
    ...
    <properties>
        <jvm.args>-Dquarkus.datasource.url=...</jvm.args>
    </properties>
    ...
</project>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using gradle and I forgot to specify this in the question.
What should I do if I use gradle?

Answer (score 0):

For gradle users, create a `gradle.properties` file in your projects root directory and add the following line

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=--add-opens java.base/sun.net=ALL-UNNAMED
```